# Log file not getting generated with log4j2

Tags: log4j2

I migrated from log4j 1.x to log4j2.
I removed log4j.properties file and created log4j2.xml file.
After migration I ran the application but not able to find the .log file.

Can anyone suggest me the mistakes

Comment: Check the default folder incase if you have not set the output path.

Comment: May I know the default folder location.

Comment: RollingFile name="LogToRollingFile" fileName="app.log"
                    filePattern="$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
   <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
   </PatternLayout>
   <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
   </Policies>
  </RollingFile>

Comment: @user2591169 your file will be stored at `$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"` because `filePattern` is location information. [reference link](filePattern) find `RollingFileAppender`

Comment: Yes you are correct @Han but  .log file not created in the filePattern location.

Comment: Actually, app.log doesn't specify a path so it will be created in whatever the directory was  the current directory when the application was started. filePattern is only for the location and name of files when they are rolled over.

Comment: @rgoers the issue is log file not generating in any of the application folders.

Comment: @user2591169 Would you find log file at your project root directory? For example, `[root directory/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz`. If it doesn't work then please upload full text `log4j2.xml ` then I think I could find what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Issue resolved after changing the path to absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add status="debug" to your configuration element in the log4j2.xml like:

```
<Configuration status="debug">
```

This will log log4j configuring itself. If you see no output then it means Log4j 2 isn't finding your configuration or Log4j isn't being used as the logging framework.